# Can't understand why the output is zeros

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist

The output desired is and IntArray of *size* numbers both positive and negative and distinct from each others.

```
fun generateArray21(size:Int):IntArray{
    val novo=IntArray(size)
    var x=0
    for (i in novo.indices){
        while (x<size){
            if (novo[i] != novo[i+1])
        novo[i]= (Math.random()*size-(size/2)).toInt()
        x++
        i+1
        }
    }
```

I tried the code above but only got zeros, im a begginer in Kotlin so i dont really know whats the problem.

Comment: _if (novo[i] != novo[i + 1])_ will always be _false_

Comment: Plus _i+1_ does not do anything

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question and the code correctly, the result would be as follows:

- for size 1: 0
- for size 2: -1, 0   (but numbers shuffled)
- for size 3: -1, 0, 1   (but numbers shuffled)
- for size 4: -2, -1, 0, 1     (but numbers shuffled)
- for size 5: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2       (but numbers shuffled)
- for size 6: -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2   (but numbers shuffled)
  – etc.

This follows from the following:

- the code *(Math.random()*size-(size/2)).toInt()*
- that the numbers need to be distinct

So a much simpler way would be to create the array and then shuffle the elements:

```
val arr = IntArray(size) { it - (size / 2) }
arr.shuffle()
```

Or to use a Sequence:

```
val result = generateSequence { (Random.nextInt(size) - (size / 2)) }
  .distinct()
  .take(size)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can generate such an array more easily, using build-in Kotlin features. Consider simplifying your code to sth like this:

```
val randomNumbers = IntArray(10) { Random.nextInt(-1000, 1000) }
```

Comment: This will not create distinct values.